# как сделать одновременно 2 опции для background

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы в дива одновременно было бы 2 свойства Но проблема в том, что 2 сразу он не учитывает и ругается что я делаю не правильно, а как сделать правильно?

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: white;
```

Comment: ругается на что? `background-repeat: *;` применяется к `background-image`, а `backgroung` просто сам по себе

Comment: Properties may be safely replaced with background shortcast

А в итоге на стринце учитывается только свойство цвета

Comment: @АнтонКравцов: Или `background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: white;` или `background: white no-repeat;`. Если указываете `background`, то располагайте его выше, чем `background-*`